# Jquery: load() function not working for div

Tags: jquery

I am displaying envision graph in the div(#graph), but it takes time of around 3 to 4 sec to load so in that time i have to display a loading symbol. After the div loads that graph should display but the thing is load function is not working for the div(#graph).

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#graph').append('<img src="images/loader.gif">'); //loading symbol           
     $('#graph').load(function(){

        //data of graph

       }); 
     }); 

    <div id='graph'></div>
```

Comment: You need to assign some id of image and hide while element is loaded

Comment: What is not working? What is the error?

Comment: user3153169 not entering into a load function

Comment: The [load event](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) is not fired for the div,as it is not associated with a URL. You could load html and insert it into the div using [this load method](https://api.jquery.com/load/) instead, which will then fire an event once the html is loaded and inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shold use url as a first parameter for load method

```
$('#graph').load('buildgraph.php', function(){
    //data is loaded
});
```

see [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1):

That should work, anyway try like this too:

```
if($('[src="images/loader.gif"]').is(':hidden')){
//do your stuff
}
```